# AES CBC алгортм

Tags: java

Подскажите кто знает, каким образом можно получить длину шифрованного ключа 192 символа?? Потому как на выходе получаю длину больше, может необходимо внести какие-то изменения в код. Прочел не мало статей и никак не получается получить желаемый результат потому как столкнулся с шифрованием впервой
использую следующий метод для шифрования

```
private static byte[] iv = "0000000000000000".getBytes();
public static String encrypt(String content, String key) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = content.getBytes("utf-8");
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] thedigest = md.digest(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
    SecretKeySpec skc = new SecretKeySpec(thedigest, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skc, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary (cipherText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, длина на выходе при блочном шифровании всегда получается кратной длине блока. В случае с AES - это 128 бит(16 байт). Вне зависимости от режима шифрования открытый текст внутри реализации дополняется до нужной длины padding`ом, который варьируется от 1 до 15 байт

Comment: у меня content 192 символа, и я хотел бы получить ключ такой же длины на выходе, но получаю я ключ большей длины и не могу понять как мне исправить это и возможно ли исправить вообще.. я использовал сайт http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index  для шифрования ключа вручную и там на выходе получаю 192 символа!!